# CD4060 with external clock pulse

Tags: clock, counter, binary

I am trying to make realtime, low power 1hr audio indicator using binary counters. I don't need display so not using decade counters or 7 segment display ICs. So I bought bunch of CD4060 binary counters, because they have inbuilt oscillator.
Later I figured out I can get reliable & accurate 1Hz/1second pulse from external, crystal based, source.
 My question is how can I configure CD4060 to use external clock instead of using timing capacitor and resistors?

Following is the functional diagram of the IC.
[image]

1. Can I give external clock directly to pin 11(RS) and leave pin 10(time resistor) and 9(time capacitor) hanging without connection?
2. Or can I give external pulse directly to pin 9 and leave pin 10 and 11 hanging?
3. will leaving other pins(11/10/9) hanging introduce errors due to external noise as it is CMOS IC? I can't ground them though.

I know, I can use CD4020 here, but I've already bought CD4060 and don't want to waste them.
I know, real time clock ICs, Arduino and like solutions can be used. I don't have microcontroller programming equipments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Can I give external clock directly to pin 11(RS) and leave pin 10(time
> resistor) and 9(time capacitor) hanging without connection?*

Yes you can but don't forget to connect MR (pin 12) to 0 volts.

> *Or can I give external pulse directly to pin 9 and leave pin 10 and 11
> hanging?*

Probably not.

> *will leaving other pins(11/10/9) hanging introduce errors due to
> external noise as it is CMOS IC? I can't ground them though.*

You should not leave pin 11 hanging. Pins 9 and 10 are outputs that happen to also connect to internal inputs.

I don't know what data sheet you used but [this one](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/HEF4060B.pdf) says this: -

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this sheet. It specifically says which pin to use for external clock.